# Graphics card shuts down my PC after it hits 50℃ temperature

Tags: gpu, desktop-computer, amd-radeon, amd-graphics-card, visual-artifacts

I have a ***R9 270X 2GB*** graphics card. I bought it a few days ago (first upgrade after 5 years) to be disappointed. I put in the graphics card, and even bought a new PSU, however when I would boot up the PC, the GPU's temperature would hover around 32℃, but then went up to hover around 42℃, and when it hit 50℃ some weird lines started appearing and the PC rebooted.

[image]

I don't know what to do anymore to be honest, I might just sell it for like 40$ for someone who knows how to fix it and save up for a ***RX 570***. I'll be thankful if someone can help me somehow.

#### My Computer Specifications:

- ***Processor:*** AMD Athlon X2 340 Dual Core
- ***Graphics card:*** Gigabyte R9 270X 2GB
- ***Motherboard:*** MSI FM2-A55M-E33
- ***BIOS:*** Up to date
- ***RAM:*** 4GB
- ***PSU:*** Zeus Force 600W
- ***OS:*** Windows 10 Professional 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The cause of problem

It clearly problem with the [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) chip. Probably a [cold solder joint](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-guide-excellent-soldering/common-problems) beneath a [BGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) chip and it is very common. The reason why the artifact on the screen appears when temperature rises is because the chip expands with temperature rise, and the small crack in the solder ball expands and it breaks the electrical circuit. It is possible that the problem is in the [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) chip itself, in the solder balls connecting the [chip die](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_(integrated_circuit)) with the [chip package](https://anysilicon.com/an-introduction-to-bga-package/).

#### The solution

Just [reballing or reflowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rework_(electronics)#Reflowing_and_reballing) the chip would probably solve the problem at least temporarily. The best bet is to replace the [BGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) chip with a new one, especially because it my be a faulty [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) chip. Many computer repair shops don't provide the service of [reballing and reflowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rework_(electronics)#Reflowing_and_reballing) [BGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) chips, and just offer chip replacement with warranty.

Comment: Thanks but sadly there was no warranty option with the purchase and I don't know how to reball and reflow BGA chips. Still thanks for the help though.

Comment: @Naix You can take it to a computer repair shop to be repaired. They will give a warranty on the repair. If the answer is satisfying give it an up vote.

Comment: If you feel adventurous - the nvidia 8800 series had a similar issue with solder joints, and people would routinely bake the cards to fix em. Worth taking a look for an option. While new to you, the R9 is almost 7 years old, and I distinctly remember them being a common second hand and a lot on the secondary market were used for bitcoin mining. Might be worth considering a modern low end card instead.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You can oven reflow graphics cards but it is risky. If you do that you must remove all heatsinks, thermal pads and backplate on the graphics card before putting it in the oven.